# Read Register via Modbus

Tags: c, modbus

I am trying to write a c program to read data for morningstar sunsaver MPPT.

This is the simple program I found in net. But my program is unable to read data from register.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "src/modbus.h"
int main(void)
{
    modbus_t *ctx;
    uint16_t tab_reg[64];
    int rc;
    int i;

    ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS0", 115200, 'N',8,1);
    if (ctx == NULL) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
       modbus_free(ctx);
       return -1;
    }

    rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 10, tab_reg);
    if (rc == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
      return -1;
    }

    for (i=0; i < rc; i++) {
      printf("reg[%d]=%d (0x%X)\n", i, tab_reg[i], tab_reg[i]);
    }

    modbus_close(ctx);
    modbus_free(ctx);
}
```

It does not work for me. I get the following error message:

**Bad file descriptor**

Comment: Is `/dev/ttyS0` file present on your system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be trying to read from wrong Serial port.

Reading from /dev/ttyS3 worked.

I later realize that serial port are from /dev/ttyS0 .. /dev/ttyS9

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [documentation from LibModBus](http://libmodbus.org/site_media/html/libmodbus.html), I think you're missing a call to [modbus_connect](http://libmodbus.org/site_media/html/modbus_connect.html).

Try connecting before reading registers:

```
ctx = modbus_new_rtu("/dev/ttyS0", 115200, 'N',8,1);
if (ctx == NULL) {
   fprintf(stderr, "Creation failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
   return -1;
}

if (modbus_connect(ctx) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Connection failed: %s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
    modbus_free(ctx);
    return -1;
}
```

Also, remember to `modbus_close` and  `modbus_free` your context before exiting due to further error conditions. For example:

```
rc = modbus_read_registers(ctx, 0, 10, tab_reg);
if (rc == -1) {
  fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", modbus_strerror(errno));
  modbus_close(ctx);
  modbus_free(ctx);
  return -1;
}
```